# Python to Format CSV File to Handle Output from SQLPlus

Tags: python, csv, sqlplus

I'm struggling to put together a python script that will access an Oracle DB using SQLPlus.
From there, it will run multiple `SELECT` queries and return them in a `.csv` file that I can open with Excel.

I have a working program, however the formatting of the `.csv` is not near how I want it and I am stumped.

What I want is something like the following... (where `|` is a column in a spreadsheet)

```
NAME | AGE | CITY
John | 50  | California
Mark | 55  | Washington 
JD   | 34  | Toronto
```

`select name, city, age from accounts;`

My code is below along with the output. Any suggestions will help.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import csv

def run_sqlplus(sql_command, connect_string):
    session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S',connect_string], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    (stdoutbytes,stderrbytes) = session.communicate(sql_command.encode('utf-8'))
    return (stdoutbytes.decode('utf-8'),stderrbytes.decode('utf-8'))
header = ['NAME','AGE',CITY']
usr_file = 'Test.csv'
connect_string = 'user/pass@MYDB'
sql_command = """SET HEADING OFF
SET MARKUP CSV ON
SET colsep ,
SET pagesize 0
SET linesize 2
SET numwidth 5
SELECT name,age,city from accounts where age > 50;
SELECT city from accounts;
"""

query_result = run_sqlplus(sql_command,connect_string)

with open(usr_file, 'w') as csvfile:
    header_writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',', lineterminator="\n",
                            escapechar='\\',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    file_writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter='|', lineterminator="\n",quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,escapechar='\\')
    header_writer.writerow(header)
    file_writer.writerow(query_result[0])
```

Returns:

```
\"|J|O|H|N|\"|   |   |\"|5|0|\"|    |   |\|"|C|A|L|I|F|O|R|N|I|A|\"|
|\
\"|M|A|R|K|\"|   |   |\"|5|5|\"|    |   |\|"|W|A|S|H|I|N|G|T|O|N|\"|
|\
|
|\
```

Note   `|`   denotes a separate column when viewing `.csv` in Excel

Comment: Why are you using a different delimiter for the header vs. the query and where is the header in your result?

Comment: @kpie my apologies i left it out. I've included